# Pfsense firewall and modem

Tags: performance, pfsense, internet-security

Should pfsense be connected directly with the ISP or should it sit behind the ISP provided modem. If so, should we use pfsense for security reasons only or to improve performance as claimed in this article https://www.pcgamer.com/i-built-my-own-super-router-out-of-old-pc-parts-and-ive-never-felt-so-powerful/.
If the PC running pfsense sits behind the ISP provided modem, then it has to process the whole traffic and I would expect the same performance although it would be dealing with a single machine running pfsense.

Answer (score 0):

If you can, it is a better idea to connect it straight to the ISP. This would let you use the full capacity of the pfSense's box as you could then connect the modem to the pfSense box, and have that for an access point with higher speeds provided you connect to a high speed port on the pfSense box. I would also expect lower latency to devices connected straight to pfSense, because they will still only be going through one box.